# MVC 3 Entity Framework - Progressive Model Update Across Several Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

All,

I have an application (Very similar to a progressive survey app) with a series of forms, across several views, that builds the data for its model (NewClub) progressively. For example, on page #1, 3 "NewClub" model properties are inserted/updated and then on page 2, 3 or 4 more "NewClub" model properties are inserted/updated, etc.

Because not all of the properties from my model are represented on each page, when I turn on the `[Required(ErrorMessage = "")]` data annotation in the model class, the ModelState is always invalid because of the required properties from the model not existing on all pages.

What's the best way to progressively update my "NewClub" model?

Thanks

**The model**

[image]

**The NewClub model class**

```
public  class NewClub
{
    public NewClub()
    {
        //Related tables here
        NewClubBuilders = new List<NewClubBuilder>();
        NewClubSponsors = new List<NewClubSponsor>();
        NewClubCaseQuestions = new List<NewClubCaseQuestion>();
        NewClubCaseAnswers = new List<NewClubCaseAnswer>();
        NewClubKitOrders = new List<NewClubKitOrder>();
        NewClubCommunityLeaders = new List<NewClubCommunityLeader>();
        NewClubRecruitingTeams = new List<NewClubRecruitingTeam>();
        NewClubRecruitingTeamDates = new List<NewClubRecruitingTeamDate>();
        NewClubRecruiterTrainingSchedules = new List<NewClubRecruiterTrainingSchedule>();
        NewClubProspects = new List<NewClubProspect>();



    }

    //Primary Key
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Club Info
    public string CreatorMasterCustomerId { get; set; }
    public string ClubMasterCustomerId { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public bool IsConverted { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name your club")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your club with a name.")]
    public string NewClubName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Location of your club")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your club location.")]
    public string NewClubLocation { get; set; }

    public string NewClubType { get; set; }


    //Lt Governor
    public string LtGovMasterCustomerId { get; set; }
    public string LtGovContact { get; set; }
    public string LtGovEmail { get; set; }
    public string LtGovPhone { get; set; }


    //Club Counselor
    public string ClubCounselorMasterCustomerId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Club counselor")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Club counselor name")]
    public string ClubCounselorContact { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Club counselor email")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Club counselor email")]
    public string ClubCounselorEmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Club counselor phone")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Club counselor phone")]
    public string ClubCounselorPhone { get; set; }


    //Build Progress
    public bool LetsGetStartedComplete { get; set; }
    public bool FormANewClubTeamComplete { get; set; }
    public bool ResourcesComplete { get; set; }
    public bool CaseForANewClubComplete { get; set; }
    public bool SubmitSiteSurveyComplete { get; set; }
    public bool NewClubBuildingKitComplete { get; set; }
    public bool StatsComplete { get; set; }
    public bool BuildScheduleComplete { get; set; }
    public bool ProspectsComplete { get; set; }
    public bool MembersComplete { get; set; }
    public bool EmailComplete { get; set; }
    public bool ClubOrganizationChecklistComplete { get; set; }
    public bool NewClubInformationComplete { get; set; }
    public bool PermanentRosterComplete { get; set; }
    public bool SubmitCharterPaymentComplete { get; set; }
    public bool ClubByLawsComplete { get; set; }

    //Date stuff
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }


    // Related tables here
    public virtual List<NewClubBuilder> NewClubBuilders { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NewClubSponsor> NewClubSponsors { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NewClubCaseQuestion> NewClubCaseQuestions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NewClubCaseAnswer> NewClubCaseAnswers { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NewClubKitOrder> NewClubKitOrders { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NewClubCommunityLeader> NewClubCommunityLeaders { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NewClubRecruitingTeam> NewClubRecruitingTeams { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NewClubRecruitingTeamDate> NewClubRecruitingTeamDates { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NewClubRecruiterTrainingSchedule> NewClubRecruiterTrainingSchedules { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NewClubProspect> NewClubProspects { get; set; } 


}
```

**The view models**

```
public class LetsGetStartedViewModel
{
    public NewClub NewClub { get; set; }
    public bool HasExistingBuildingClubs { get; set; }
}





public class FormANewClubTeamViewModel
{   
    public NewClub NewClub { get; set; }

    //All club sponsors
    public List<NewClubSponsor> Sponsors { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to have a different model per `View` -- i.e., to work with `ViewModels` instead of with one shared `Model`. Each `ViewModel` should of course only contain those properties that are relevant to that particular `View`.

Then your `Controller` methods must temporarily save the `ViewModel` from page *n* before moving the wizard on to page *n* + 1, and finally, when the user clicks *Submit* on the last page, all data must be submitted to a final `Controller` method.

You can do that by building a complete `Model` that contains the other `ViewModels` as properties. The last wizard page's `Controller` method then builds up that `Model` and submits it to the Submit button's `Controller` method.

Comment: So would you simply retask the existing viewmodels? For example:  public class FormANewClubTeamViewModel{}

Comment: Indeed. Feed only to a View what it needs, store the rest somewhere else until you need it.